# Freetds writes numeric as integer in the database

Tags: sql-server, freetds, freebcp

I use `freebcp` to bulkcopy data to SQL Server. It works fine except for numerical values which end up being truncated to integer. The column in the database is a `FLOAT` so it can handle values with decimals.

Command

```
freebcp MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable in /path/to/myfile.txt -c -S MyServer -U MyUser -P MyPassword
```

MyTable has 5 columns, the first are 2 INTEGER, the others are FLOAT.

Sample from `myfile.txt`

```
19344   303634  -0.419398400743657  -1.38936409312037   0.550567291633061
19345   303634  -1.59787440264054   -2.05068741446749   -1.14506139081359
```

is stored as

```
19344   303634  0   -1  1
19345   303634  -2  -2  -1
```

How to fix this?

Note: I'm using `freebcp` under Ubuntu. When using `bcp` under Windows the floating columns are exported correctly while using almost the same syntax (just replace `freebcp` with `bcp` and use a thrusted connection).

```
bcp MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable in /path/to/myfile.txt -c -S MyServer -T
```

Answer (score 0):

> Questioner originally stated data type of three columns with decimal
>   places was `NUMERIC`. Questioner edited question, changing data type
>   to `FLOAT`, in response to this answer.

`NUMERIC` is functional equivalent to `DECIMAL`. [msdn - NUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx)

Are the *precision* and *scale* defined for the `NUMERIC` columns in the SQL table? When they are not defined the default *precision* is 18 and the *scale* is 0. Therefore if they are not defined you will have 0 places to the right of the decimal place.

If you cannot predict the number of decimal places (*scale*) you need, then the `FLOAT` data type is more appropriate. [msdn - FLOAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773(v=sql.105).aspx)

Otherwise, you need to set the *precision* and *scale* for `NUMERIC`.

Comment: The data type of the non-integer fields is `FLOAT`. I've updated my question.